# If $\gcd(a,b)=1$, then there exists integers $x$ and $y$ such that $xa + yb = 1$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Did not find this from this website...

If $$ \gcd(a,b)=1,$$ then there exists integers $x$ and $y$ such that $$xa+yb=1.$$

Now, the tip is to use particular corollary, that states:

The class $[m]_{n}$ generates $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}\Leftrightarrow \gcd(m,n)=1.$

I am totally lost with the corollary.

Let's assume that $\gcd(m,n)=1$. Then, $[m]_{n}$ generates $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$.

OK! Then what?

There is also follow up, where I have to prove the converse. I am familiar with Bezout's lemma.

Comment: Are you trying to prove that $gcd(a,b)=1$ implies that you can find $x,y$ such that $xa+yb=1$ using the corollary?

Comment: This is a particular case of Bézout's identity which you can read here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity

Comment: Yes I am, Grumpy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a$ and $b$ be coprime. Then $[a]_b$ generates $\mathbb Z/b\mathbb Z$. So there is some $x$ such that $x[a]_b=[1]_b$. By definition, this means there exists a $y$ such that $xa-1=yb$, as desired.